# How to prevent npm from resolving devDependencies on production install

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm building a microservice app in a monorepo containing a bunch of microservices and a commons package. This commons package is never published to npm. (packages are managed with yarn workspaces)

Using parcel, the commons package is bundled into the production code, so I don't need to install it at run time.

Each microservice runs in its own docker container. So, when I build the docker container, Ideally, I'd want to ignore this "commons" dependency and install all the other ones. AFAIK, the only way to do this is to place the "commons" package in devDependencies.

However, it seems that even if I add it only to devDependencies and run `npm i --only=production`, npm still tries to *resolve* the package and still throws an `ETARGET` error.

Is there some way to *completely* ignore the devDependencies? My only other Idea is to write a script that removes the devDependencies field from the package.json before running npm install, but I wanted to ask here first to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Comment: Only packages without "commons" packages should be installed after typing `npm install`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a GitHub issue on the npm/cli repo tracking this issue [here (#4967)](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4967), where this behaviour is categorized as a bug.

So to answer your question, as far as the current status of the GitHub issue indicates, the intended behaviour is that `devDependencies` don't get attempted to be resolved in `--production` mode, and you shouldn't need to do anything extra to get this behaviour once the fix is made. I don't think you are missing anything.

The workaround you have thought of sounds reasonable to me.

On the GitHub issue, you can indicate "me too" with a thumbs up reaction (please don't spam the comments with "me too" comments).

Answer (score -2):

To install packages only at production without devDependencies,

```
npm install --production
```

[Docs about npm install is here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install).

Comment: I know. I tried that, but even though it doesn't install the dev dependencies, it still seems to try to resolve them.

Comment: I confirm, dev dependencies are resolved in production mode even if they are not installed. Any resolution error (registry authentication for example) causes an error and block the install process.